# Google map kml with 2 points and descriptions but same description displays for both

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a test page at http://www.noosawaters.org/Google/noosawaters_test.html which has 2 polygons with a point in each one. Each point has a different description but the same description appears for both. There is a link to the kml file at top left.

I have another test page at http://www.noosawaters.org/Google/states_test.html where the code is identical apart from the coordinates yet the descriptions display correctly. There is a link to the kml file at top left.

Can anybody spot what makes one work but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the Point coordinates are in the wrong polygons.  Why that confuses KmlLayer, I can't say:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/NoosaWaters11.kml?nocache=121213

The star for "Lock and weir" is in the polygon for the "Noosa Croquet Club" and the start from the "Noosa Croquet Club" is in the polygon for "Lock and weir"

It is possible that the star for "Lock and weir" is not clickable and I am just seeing the infoWindow for the Polygon it is on top of.